# How to prevent arithmetic operations between different kinds of integers?

Tags: c, compilation, type-safety

I am working on a debugger (in C) which deals with embedded system whose memory has an addressable size of 16-bits. This means that at address x you have a 16-bits value, at (x + 1) you have another 16-bits value, etc. When working with data that comes from the target memory, I therefore have to convert the lengths between target bytes lengths and host bytes lengths. If I want to read 10 (16-bit) bytes from the target, I therefore have to allocate a 20 (8-bit) bytes in the debugger, which runs on the host.

A big number of bugs come from the fact that I forget to do these conversion, and I do semantically invalid arithmetic operations, such as adding an host memory address (i.e. the buffer allocated on my host) to a length in target bytes lengths. This makes no sense, and the length should be converted to an equivalent host bytes length prior to the addition (effectively multiply the length by 2).

My question is: is there any way that I can get the compiler to protect me from my own mistakes?

Both length types are integers. Is there way, for example, through type magic, to tell the compiler that this kind of integer can't be added to this other type of integers, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a 16 bit byte?

Comment: C isn't really "strongly" typed when it comes to integers--it just knows what the underlying types are and lets you mix them. You might want to take a look at Go.

Comment: You're probably better off wrapping everything in `struct`s or otherwise manipulating everything through functions, rather than directly with arithmetic.

Comment: As @Paul Griffiths said (use functions). That also gives you the ability to prevent the debugger reading addresses that will cause the program to malfunction - for example reading a status register that then clears that status, so the target program never sees it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: This was my feeling. Unfortunately, a switch of language is not possible (we are modifying gdb, which is C). As for a switch to a struct, it would be possible, but changing that throughout the gdb source code would be a titanic job!

Comment: As @PaulGriffiths says, it could be structures. Or even unions (see [this](https://github.com/alexfru/TypeTraitsInC)), in which you can include type information verifiable by special macros at compile time.